# One folder having two different locations on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: directory, shared-folders

I want to have the same folder at two different locations in my Ubuntu. If I update something in one, it should also get updated in the other location.

How can I make it happen?

Comment: do those 2 locations need to be physical (as in 2x taking up space) or can they be links?

Comment: A `symbolic link` is the simplest solution to your requirement and is not dependent on superuser privileges. `man ln` for more information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [**bind mounts**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/251553).

Suppose you have an existing directory `/home/pandey/original` and 
want to *mirror* it to `/home/pandey/mirror` so that everything you
do in either of them is automatically done in the other one as well.

This doesn't require any syncing or copying between the two directories.
A *bind mount* is just another *view* to the original directory and what 
happens in one also happens in the other.

1. Create (as your user) the new directory `/home/pandey/mirror`:

   ```
   mkdir /home/pandey/mirror
   ```
2. *bind-mount* the original directory to the newly created path.
   This requires root access:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /home/pandey/original /home/pandey/mirror
   ```
3. Enjoy.

To undo this, simply

```
sudo umount /home/pandey/mirror
rmdir /home/pandey/mirror
```

See also this question and its outstanding self-answer 
over on stackexchange [about bind-mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/251553).

Comment: +1, For sure this way is faster than the way I proposed;

Comment: Would'd `cd /home/pandey; ln -s original mirror` have the same effect and not require sudo rights?

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering why people are proposing these roundabout solutions while this sounds like a classic use case for a simple sym link. What's the advantage? As far as I can see none of the advantages listed in the referenced question seem to apply here.

Comment: @doneal24 I agree: symbolic linking has the same effect from a practical view point and does not require fundamental system changes and administrator privileges.

Comment: The linked question on bind mounts has a nice list of possible use cases. Just needing another named path to a directory is not one of them.

Comment: Bind mounts do have a performance advantage, abeilt *very* small. In general I would strongly advise to use symlinks unless you explicitly know you want bind mounts.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49623/are-there-any-drawbacks-from-using-mount-bind-as-a-substitute-for-symbolic-lin

Answer (score 44):

As pointed out in the comments but not as a proper answer:

In many cases, a symbolic link is the easiest solution.

You can create them easily on the command line (using the `ln` command with `-s` parameter).
You can create them easily using a GUI as well: Most file browsers (nautilus, ...) let you create a symbolic link using drag and drop (like for moving a file) while holding down a modifier key (CTRL+SHIFT).

Example for command line usage:

```
$ mkdir first_dir
$ ln -s ./first_dir ./second_dir
$ ls 
first_dir  second_dir

$ touch ./first_dir/test_1
$ touch ./second_dir/test_2

$ ls ./first_dir 
test_1  test_2

$ ls ./second_dir
test_1  test_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting a crontab job:

- Open your terminal and type `crontab -e`
- Press `i` in order to activate the insert mode of your vim editor.

You can enter the command you want to be done there, so you can copy all files of the folder in another folder. For example, if you want to copy all files in `/home/user/folder_name` to `/home/user/public` you should insert this command in your `crontab` file:

```
rsync /home/user/folder_name -r /home/user/public
```

This will copy all files in the desired interval. If you want to copy all files at 21:30 every day your edit should be:

```
 30 21 * * *  rsync /home/user/folder_name -r /home/user/public
```

For more information about *crontab* look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) or use `man crontab`.

Comment: I would probably use bind mounts as @PerlDuck, given is an easy and maintainable way to do it. I would not use cronjobs since this could lead to all sort of performance problems on your machine if you end up syncing a folder into multiple locations and the files in the first folder are very large or numerous. My company is using this approach to emulate Dropbox/Drive behavior and now that we reached a large number of files, some of them having GB's of size, the solution simply does not scale anymore.

Comment: This is two directories, not one.